# Formula to Calculate Confidence Interval of Marginal Means

Tags: confidence-interval, interaction, mean, standard-error, marginal-distribution

What is the formula for the marginal means confidence interval in a regression analysis?

Let us have the following regression

$$Y = b_0 + b_1X + b_2Z + b_3 XZ + b_4 \mathrm{Cov}_1 + b_5 \mathrm{Cov}_2$$

If I get it right the marginal means would be calculated holding $\mathrm{Cov}_1$ and $\mathrm{Cov}_2$ at mean and entering $X$ and $Z$ values of interest, e.g. mean+/-SD which results in 6 marginal means.

Assuming all variables are standardized and X and Z are dummies (0,1), the marginal means would be following:

- X = 1, Z = 0: marginalMean = $_0 + _1$
- X = 0, Z = 0: marginalMean = $_0$
- X = 1, Z = 1: marginalMean = $_0 + _1 + _2 + _3$
- X = 0, Z = 1: marginalMean = $_0 + _2$

The covariates are hold at their mean = 0 thus do not influence the marginal mean. Another example without covariates can be found in the definition of [marginal mean in Online Statistics Education](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/glossary/marginal_mean.html).

Thank you in for your help in advance.

Best, Tobi.

P.S.: I am aware that SPSS or JAMOVI can calculate marginal mean including confidence interval, but they give me different results and I would love to understand the underlying formula.

Comment: Could you explain what you understand a "marginal mean" to be?

Comment: In my understanding the marginal mean is "the mean response for each factor, adjusted for any other variables in the (regression) model." (Source: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-report-estimated-marginal-means-in-spss-glm/). So in my understanding it is calculated like described above.

Comment: Your description appears to involve "holding" the values of two variables, "entering" the values of two other variables and then doing something with means and SDs--but what all this really amounts to is unclear.  It doesn't seem to correspond to what you state in your comment.  Could you edit the post to explain or illustrate what you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added an example and hope I could clarify things?

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured out an answer myself. Regarding this page https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/regression-confidence-prediction-intervals they call it “Confidence (Mean) Intervals” and describe the calculation there as:

$$\hat{y}_h \pm t_{\alpha / 2, n - 2} \sqrt{MSE \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})^2}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x}^2)} \right)}$$

Did I get this right?

Best, Tobi.

Comment: I didn't see a solution to your problem on the referenced site: could you describe what you think the solution is?

Comment: I tried to add the formula. They describe the solution under point "Confidence (Mean) Intervals"

Comment: That's a confidence interval for predicted values with a single regressor.  It doesn't work with your situation, nor does it answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying. My thoughts were if covariate1 and covariate2 are keep at mean which equals zero and I enter the respective values of each dummy (0,1) it works like this. Could you direct me to the appropriate way to calculate the confidence intervals?

Comment: Use the estimated covariance matrix of the parameter estimates to compute the standard errors of estimate and construct confidence intervals in the usual way.

Comment: Sound good at one point I was thinking about using the standard errors of the estimates. But I was not sure what formula to use to construct the confidence intervals. What would you consider the usual way in this case? You have a link or formula?